# Copy/Paste a selection from Photoshop to Illustrator "round" pixels

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, pixel, copy-and-paste

I'm copy from Photoshop CS6 this selection:

[image]

Which is exactly 16x50 pixels, correctly snapped with grid.

Once I paste in Illustrator CC 2019, it round both pixel sizes and grid position:

[image]

Why 15,998x49,994px at 121,999, 144,997 position?

Can I keep original pixels and preserve sizes?

Or do I need to manually fix it?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It's only a rounding error. You can ignore it. There's nothing to fix.   Also why didn't you just create the image in Illustrator? There's no need to use Photosohop at all for this.

Answer (score 2):

**I think it's default behaviour**

The only possible reason as i think must be again photoshop pixel characteristic vs illustrators vector characteristic.

so the steps i followed was changing dpi and images etc and i figured out that whenever you embed **`physical file`** it always embedded with scaling of **`100%`** while same file opened in photoshop and when pasted it into illustrator it embedded with scaling of **`99.987%`** . i tested same with low pixel resolutions like 4*4 px etc and it's also embedded with **`99.987%`** but the display will show complete 4*4 instead of some float value so below is my conclusion

From my perspective : this can't be changed since it must be algorithm issue of illustrator which embed images from clipboard and there might not be any other solution.

the only logical solution is make your dpi something which converts **`99.987 ratio to 100% and that dpi is exact 72.0093612`** and when i made my canvas to 72.0093612 dpi and then exported the magical thing was shocking since if photoshop really converted it to float DPI then illustrator image should be embedded with 100% instead of again 99.987 so basically you have no chances other than resizing manually.

**figure 1 : embedding physical file**

[image]

**figure 2 : embedding clipboard file**

[image]

**figure 3 : values while embedding @99.987% exact in low resolution float in high**

[image][image]

TLDR :  Don't worry about placed files since it's very low different and it can be overrided easily but if you talking about changing default then sorry it shouldn't be possible as far as i know

-Best regards

Design Phoenix

Comment: It seems Photoshop use ppi as integer and illustrator as float? Thats the rounding error...

Comment: yeah that might be point. anyway but sorry for your problem since that's all I can help :) even we all face same. it jus't maybe i didn't noticed it at all since always i do scaling manually :P

Answer (score 1):

Verify the psd document has exactly 72 ppi as resolution

[image]

If that's the case, there shouldn't be any problem:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it has 72 of course

Comment: @Danielillo I think we can't change this property since it is some core level issue :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure changing PPI would matter. But it's strange, it's almost like you are working in... megapixels??? Test it out on blank documents and try again, if it's still giving you issues reinstall. I just had a bug last week where my illustrator snap to pixel grid worked fine, but the visual lines themselves were rotated 1 degree counterclockwise. nothing like a fresh clean install to keep me from ripping out my hair that I don't have :)